# formation of diff. eqn for $\displaystyle y=ae^x+bxe^x+cx^2e^x\;$

Tags: calculus

How can i form Differential equation for $\displaystyle y=ae^x+bxe^x+cx^2e^x\;$(Where $a,b,c$ are arbitrary constant.)

$\bf{My \; Try::}$Given $3$ arbitrary constant, so we will differentiate it $3$ times.

So Given $y=ae^x+bxe^x+cx^2 e^x$

Now diff. both side w. r .to $x$

So $y'=ae^x+b(xe^x+e^x)+c(x^2e^x+2xe^x)\Rightarrow y'=y+be^x+2cxe^x$

Now again diff. both side w. r .to $x$

So $y''=y'+be^x+2c(xe^x+e^x)\Rightarrow y''=y'+(y'-y)+2ce^x\Rightarrow y''=2y'-y+2ce^x$

Now diff. both side w. r .to $x$

So $y'''=2y''-y'+2ce^x\Rightarrow y'''=2y''-y'+(y''-2y'+y)\Rightarrow y'''=3y''-3y'+y$

So Differential equation is $y'''-3y''+3y'-y=0$

can we solve it any short method, If yes then plz explain here

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll eventually learn that $x$'s in front of exponential solutions correspond to repeated roots. Thus, if
$$ y = Ae^x + Bx e^x + Cx^2e^x $$
We know the characteristic of the ODE we want is
$$ P( \lambda) = ( \lambda -1)^3 = \lambda^3 - 3 \lambda ^2 + 3 \lambda - 1 $$
Hence,
$$ y''' - 3 y'' + 3 y' - y = 0$$
is the ODE we seek.